# How to filter array using key value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this array so how can i filter using key value i want **per_hour**  inbetween 10 to  70 and **gender** = M

but in my case i have to add condition if per_hour parameter set or gender parameter set if both set than combine result will display other wise set parameter based result

so how can i filer using per_hour and gender both please provide sollution

```
Array
(
    [0] = Array
        (            
            [tutor] = Array
                (                    
                    [per_hour] =50                    
                    [gender] = F
               )

        )

    [1] =&gt; Array
        (


            [tutor] =Array
                (

                    [per_hour] = 50

                    [gender] = M

                )

        )

    [2] =&gt; Array
        (

            [tutor] =Array
                (                   
                    [per_hour] = 818

                    [gender] = F

                )

        ) 

)
```

Comment: have you tried anything.....

Comment: do some effort and share some code. this platform is not the free source code provider

Answer (score 2):

You can set a function as array_filter's callback to check for per_hour and gender

```
$filter = array_filter($array, function($e){
    return ($e['tutor']['per_hour'] == 50 && $e['tutor']['gender'] == 'M');
});

print_r($filter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try **[array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)** function to itrate.
Eg :

```
$myarray=array(array('tutor'=>array('genedr'=>'M','per_hour'=>50)));
$result_array=array_map($myarray,function($ar){ return ($ar['tutor']['per_hour']==50 && $ar['tutor']['gender']=="M") })?$ar['tutor']:'';
$filterdArray=array_filter($result_array);
print_r($result_array);
```

Comment: This will return a syntax error on your `array_map()` line

Comment: but i have to make condition if per_hour or gender was set

Comment: @ErNilayParekh, given that you haven't posted any attempts, check Emerald's answer. That should work on your case

Comment: no but in my case i have  to add condition if per_hour parameter set or gender parameter set if both set than combine result will display other wise set parameter based result

Comment: Why use both `array_map` and `array_filter` when you could just use `array_filter` by itself?

Comment: @ErNilayParekh Emerald's answer already solves your problem. You just need to change the the callback to return what you need based on your conditions. Just to remind, SO is not a coding service.